When $R$ is an arbitrary ring and the left regular module $_R R$ is injective, can we get that the global dimension of $R$ must be $0$ or $\infty$?
If $R$ is a finite-dimensional algebra over a field $k$ and the left regular module $_R R$ is injective, we conclude that the global dimension of $R$ is either $0$ or $\infty$.
This raises the question: If $R$ is an arbitrary ring and the left regular module $_R R$ is injective, can we also conclude that the global dimension of $R$ is $0$ or $\infty$? In other words, are the projective modules over $R$ also injective? Is there a counterexample?

If the continuum hypothesis is true, then the countable direct product of fields is a counterexample. Are you wanting a counterexample that doesn’t depend on set-theoretic assumptions?

@Jeremy Rickard Thank you very much for your counterexample involving the countable direct product of fields. On another note, I’d like to know if there’s a counterexample that doesn’t rely on set-theoretic assumptions.

As you discovered here this 'zero or infinite global dimension' thing amounts to being quasi-Frobenius, and there are many self-injective rings that are not quasi-Frobenius.

There are self-injective rings that are not quasi-Frobenius, but still have infinite global dimension. In fact, I haven't thought of an example which has finite global dimension without assuming something like the continuum hypothesis. Do you know any examples?

@JeremyRickard Not being well acquainted with global dimension, I can't say yes.  Turning toward the DaRT query it seems there are at least 8 known self-injective non-QF rings one could try first.  Global dimension is one of the more neglected dimensions measured there. I notice several of them have weak global dimension 0.  If you figure out any of the global dimensions there positively, I would be really interested in incorporating your findings...

@JeremyRickard Just checking: the first "have infinite global dimension" was meant to be "finite global dimension," right?

No, I did mean "infinite". For example, the product of $\aleph_\omega$ fields is a self-injective, but not QF, ring that has infinite global dimension (regardless of the continuum hypothesis). The product of countably many fields is self-injective but not QF, but may or may not have infinite global dimension, depending on set-theoretic assumptions.

@JeremyRickard it's just that in the last half of the commeent you were asking about finite global dimension examples, so I wanted to make sure which type of example you were asking about.  I think the last half is clear, but the first sentence primes the reader for the second half to be about infinite examples. I think  I understand now that the first sentence is meant to say "I don't need any examples of that type, now how about the finite case"

It feels like it'd be pretty astounding if crafting finite examples required CH in all cases...
